# Some detail Cartan structural equation

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $R^{n}$ be an n-dimensional Euclidean space. And let $\left\{e_{1},e_{2},...,e_{n}\right\}$ be the orthogonal frame bundle on $R^{n}$. Now we have $d e_{i}=w^{i}_{j}e_{i}$ where we use Einstein summation. Now we think of $w$ as a matrix with entries $w^{i}_{j}$. Then I know how to prove that if we choose fixed frame, w is an uniquely determined anti-symmetric matrix. Now I want to prove that $dw=w\wedge w$ which is special version of Cartan structural equation.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Differentiate the equation $de_i=\sum \omega^j_i e_j$. (You have indices wrong!) Remember at the end that the $e_j$ form a basis.

Comment: Appreciate, I got the answer. And I have one more question. $dw=w\wedge w$ is not true in general Reimannian manifold.  Which part of above calculation can not be carried out in Riemannian manifold?

Comment: And is the orthogonality of basis nesessary?

Comment: This is the structure equation for any (matrix) Lie group $G$, where $(\omega^j_i)$ is the right-invariant $\mathfrak g$-valued 1-form (called the Maurer-Cartan form).